# How to add a text at specific location in json file using python or bat?

Tags: python, json, batch-file

I have a json file like as follows:

```
{
"category": {
    "gender": {
        "male": "A",
        "female": "B"
    },
    "age": {
        "young": 25
    },
    "dob": {
        "dob_list": [
            "crap"
        ]
    }
},
"sample": {
    "game1": {
        "title": "<arg>",
        "player": "john",
    },
    "game2": {
        "title": "<arg>",
        "game_location": "C:/game/<arg>/crap.exe",
        "game_root": "C:/games/"
    }
}
```

}

So i want to have some runtime arguments against "arg" in above json file passed from some python script or bat file. So can anyone suggest me how can i acheive that and which option is better to pass values a python script or bat file?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `json.load()` on the file and then manipulate the contents of the file using dict comprehension

```
with open("file.json",'r') as f:
    mydict = json.load(f)

mydict['sample']['game1']['title'] = yourValue
with open('file.json','w') as f:
    f.write(str(mydict))
```

Comment: it does not writting anything inside json